# Compare all rows of a particular column

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Shared Function ValidateDate(dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean

    Dim Currentdate As Date = Date.Now()
    Dim Rows As New List(Of String)

    Dim result As Boolean = True
    For Each Row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        If Not Currentdate Is  Then
    Next      

    Return result

End Functionhere
```

I want to compare rows of datecolumn of `DataTable` with the current date and return whether or not it's matches the current date.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It seems the OP is new here @rory.ap, you do have `edit` permissions correct? How about helping the OP out, I am aware this is not in **form** of a question `I want to compare rows of datecolumn of datatable with the currentdate and return true if it satisfies the condition vb.net`, but I am sure you understand what the OP is ***asking***... `I want to compare rows of datecolumn of datatable with the currentdate ` this seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: What condition?

Comment: I am having a datatable with some columns. one of its column is date column. I want to compare all rows of date column with the current date using for loop by vb.net code.

Comment: `Dim blnValid As Boolean = dataTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToList().Where(Function(r) r("columnname") <> currentdate).Any()` havent tested this but its an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  d("Columnname") what is d here?

Comment: `d`? not sure what you mean, refresh your webpage... `columnname` is your date column name...

Comment: can i add a condition that  if date in all rows is current of future it should return true . if it is less than the current date should return false. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

code:

Private Shared Function ValidateDate(dataTable As DataTable) As Boolean

```
    Dim Currentdate As Date = Today
    Dim result As Boolean = True
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        If Not CDate(row.Item("ReportDate")) >= Currentdate Then
            result = False
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Thank you for your responses .I used this method to validate date in every row of datecolumn

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help (not tested but should work)...This approach gives you a list with the rows who matched your criteria

```
    Dim Currentdate As Date = Today
    Dim lst as New List(of DataRow)

    For each row as DataRow in datatable.Rows
        If CDate(row.Items(index or columname)) = currentdate Then
            lst.Add(row)
    Next

    return lst
```

Notice you have time in `date` datatype, which will be 0:00:00 if you dont give it explicitly. 
(Should be no Problem, if all valuesa are only dates "with default 0:00:00 time") If not you will **get only `true` if date & time are the same **!

So you should use Today instead of Date.Now().. Every time you call `Date.Now()` you get the actual date & actual time. With `Today` you get actual date and time = 0:00:00.

Comment: `DataRow` doesn't have a property of `Cells`... it's `Item`. Also you are returning `True` if it's found, but what if the next row it's `False`... this solution is all wrong.

Comment: Cells should mean Items....my error was thinking in DataGridView. And yeah I have missunderstood the question. I thought he just wanted to know if there is a given date somewhere in the rows at least one time....

Comment: I understood, `all rows` meaning every row, not just one.

Comment: Yes I know, sometime is better to read 2 times before answering...I already edited my answer